# Dozer mapping with abstract class

Tags: java, constructor, mapping, javabeans, dozer

I am using [dozer](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/) to map between bean and model with annotation approach. Everything works well with most of the classes.

But recently i faced 1 issue when my bean has protected constructor with 1 parameter. Because this constructor is being used in some places with `super` keyword.

Below is Sample example:

**TestBean.java:**

```
abstract public class TestBean{

  public enum Type {
    ALL, FIELD, QUERY, HIERARCHY
  }

  public enum Sort {
    COUNT, INDEX, VALUE
  }

  private Type type;
  private String description;
  private Sort sort;
  
  public FacetBean() {
  }

  protected FacetBean(FacetBean from) {
    setId(from.getId());
    description = from.description;
    sort = from.sort;  
  }

  public Type getType() {
    return type;
  }

  public void setType(Type type) {
    this.type = type;
  }

  public String getDescription() {
    return description;
  }

  public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
  }

  public Sort getSort() {
    return sort;
  }

  public void setSort(Sort sort) {
    this.sort = sort;
  }
}
```

Below is the sample code for my model.

**TestModel.java**

```
public class TestModel{

  public enum Type {
    ALL, FIELD, QUERY, HIERARCHY
  }

  public enum Sort {
    COUNT, INDEX, VALUE
  }

  private Type type;
  private String description;
  private Sort sort;
  

  public Type getType() {
    return type;
  }

  public void setType(Type type) {
    this.type = type;
  }

  public String getDescription() {
    return description;
  }

  public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
  }

  public Sort getSort() {
    return sort;
  }

  public void setSort(Sort sort) {
    this.sort = sort;
  }
}
```

I am using `org.dozer.mapper` to map between model and bean.

Below is working code:

`mapper.map(testBean, TestModel.class)` --> **WORKING**

If i try the otherway round, then it's giving me
`mapper.map(testModel, TestBean.class)` --> **NOT WORKING**

> org.dozer.MappingException: java.lang.InstantiationException

*Any idea how to solve this issue?* (I can't change TestBean.java as it is very old class and being used in many places, I have created TestModel.java recently to map the data of TestBean.java to it and return as API response)

Thanks!

Comment: TestBean is defined as abstract and you cannot instantiate abstract classes in Java.  You would have to map to a concrete class.

Comment: Yes that is what i did. But i just wanted to know that is there any way to achieve this behind the scene using dozer or not. Thanks @JohnCamerin

Comment: So, the answer is, it depends. For instance, I have dto style api beans and separate JPA entities and I use Dozer for mapping. I have several cases where there is an abstract base class and multiple concrete subclasses. In those cases, the hierarchy is mirrored and I have mappings specified at the concrete classes. However, when I call Dozer, I call it with the abstract types and Dozer is smart enough to figure out the concrete classes and find the mappings.   Another option would be to use a custom bean factory and write the code that figures which concrete class to construct.